# Find a way to check this table without if else statements

Tags: php, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

I have the following image to show what I need to do.

[image]

The data I have is the one marked in blue, and according to that I need to get the results of the one marked in red.

So for example my client have the next data:

| ingreso | bancarizacion | ult 6 | ult 12 | ult 24 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SI | SI | NO | NO | NO |

The result will be:

| Calificacion | Tipo Clientes | Resultado |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | APTO |

Can anyone help me achieve this in PHP without nesting a lot of if/else statements?

I need a function to return an array with the 3 results.

```
function checkClient($ingreso, $bancarizacion, $ult6, $ult12, $ult24){
    $data =  [];

    // conditions
    
    return $data;    
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please clarify what input should result in what outputs, what's the logic that you want to apply, with or without if/else?

Comment: @MarkusAO I marked an example in the question, the second table that says: 'the result will be'. 

The inputs are the columns marked in blue, ingreso, bancarizacion, ult6, ult12, ult24, and the outputs the one marked in red, calificacion, tipo clientes and resultado.

I don't know what to implement without using if/else, I'm sure that there must be a better and cleaner solution maybe with objects or using database.

Comment: Thanks. Well I spent a moment staring at the data, the logic of how the outputs happen is clear. A lookup map is a simple, clean way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to accomplish this without conditional constructs is *concatenating the relevant fields into "lookup strings"* and then *matching the resulting strings with mapped results*. We're using the [match](https://www.php.net/match) statement here (PHP 8), but you could also do associative array lookups.

```
function checkClient($ingreso, $bancarizacion, $ult6, $ult12, $ult24) {

    // Calificacion => Mapped from: ingreso + bancarizacion

    $calci = match($ingreso . $bancarizacion) {
        'SISI' => 'A',
        'SINO' => 'B',
        'NOSI' => 'C',
        'NONO' => 'D',
        default => '?'
    };
    
    // Tipo, Resultado => Mapped from: ULT6 + 12 + 24

    $tipo_resu = match($ult6 . $ult12 . $ult24) {
        'NONONO' => [1, 'APTO'], 
        'NONOSI' => [2, 'APTO'], 
        'NOSINO' => [3, 'REVISARE'], 
        'NOSISI' => [4, 'REVISARE'], 
        'SI' => [5, 'NO APTO'],
        default => [0, 'OBSCURO']
    };
    
    return [
        'Calificacion' => $calci,
        'Tipo Clientes' => $tipo_resu[0],
        'Resultado' => $tipo_resu[1]
    ]; 
}
```

*No ifs or buts required. :)* Map/case lookups, whether using `match`, `switch` or associative arrays, are often a convenient way to avoid elaborate if/else constructs and chains of multiple evaluations. You *could* also do `match(true) {` with arms like `$ult6 == 'NO' && $ult12 == 'NO' && $ult24 == 'SI' => [2, 'APTO']`, but concatenation is compact and sufficient for this case.

You could also implement this logic on a database level e.g. with case statements, though maintaining it would likely be more work. I'll leave that exercise for someone else to tackle.

---

P.S. Just to illustrate the array lookup way of doing this. The only difference with match here is that, instead of having everything in one statement, we define our map separately, look for an array key, and provide a default value with the `??` operator if no matching key exists.

```
$calci_map = [
    'SISI' => 'A',
    'SINO' => 'B',
    'NOSI' => 'C',
    'NONO' => 'D'
];

$calci = $calci_map[$ingreso . $bancarizacion] ?? '?';
```

Likewise with the second lookup set. It really doesn't make much difference which approach you use in this case. If you're not on PHP 8 yet, you obviously have to use array lookup.

Comment: Sure thing. Match is a very cool addition to PHP 8, simplifies a lot of things. You _could_ just as well do an array lookup. I've added an example in the end of the answer. But I like to pimp `match` because it's one of the main reasons I bothered upgrading PHP, so. :))

Answer (score 0):

You have to do manual indexes for each column, but it has no reason to do it by yourself since it is one of the things that databases do.
If you'll put this data in a database (let's say MongoDB) and set indexes for all these columns. You'll be able to find matches pretty fast with an elegant code.

Comment: I'm working with MySql, I'm interested in doing it that way, can you please extend your answer a bit? I don't get this "it has no reason to do it by yourself since it is one of the things that databases do"

Comment: You cannot achieve it without if/else using just an array. You can try to create naive table indexing on data initialization, using Map where the key is cell values and value is row indices. So by client input, you'll be able to find all matched rows indices and display them. But do it only if you really have no choice, otherwise, I hardly suggest not inventing bicycle and use  db queries for it.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this before I saw @MarkusAO answer. This worked, but I will try ur answer now that I saw it.

```
function verificarTipoCliente($ingreso, $bancarizacion,$ult6, $ult12, $ult24){

    $data = "$ingreso-$bancarizacion-$ult6-$ult12-$ult24";

    $config = array(
        // A
        "SI-SI-NO-NO-NO" => array("calificacion" => "A", "tipo" => 1, "resutado" => "APTO", "tasa" => "SI", "promo" => "SI"),
        "SI-SI-NO-NO-SI" => array("calificacion" => "A", "tipo" => 2, "resutado" => "APTO", "tasa" => "SI", "promo" => "SI"),
        "SI-SI-NO-SI-NO" => array("calificacion" => "A", "tipo" => 3, "resutado" => "CON OBSERVACIONES", "tasa" => "SI", "promo" => "SI"),
        "SI-SI-NO-SI-SI" => array("calificacion" => "A", "tipo" => 4, "resutado" => "CON OBSERVACIONES", "tasa" => "SI", "promo" => "SI"),
        "SI-SI-SI--" => array("calificacion" => "A", "tipo" => 5, "resutado" => "NO APTO", "tasa" => "SI", "promo" => "SI"),
        // B
        "SI-NO-NO-NO-NO" => array("calificacion" => "B", "tipo" => 1, "resutado" => "APTO", "tasa" => "SI", "promo" => "SI"),
        "SI-NO-NO-NO-SI" => array("calificacion" => "B", "tipo" => 2, "resutado" => "APTO", "tasa" => "SI", "promo" => "SI"),
        "SI-NO-NO-SI-NO" => array("calificacion" => "B", "tipo" => 3, "resutado" => "CON OBSERVACIONES", "tasa" => "SI", "promo" => "SI"),
        "SI-NO-NO-SI-SI" => array("calificacion" => "B", "tipo" => 4, "resutado" => "CON OBSERVACIONES", "tasa" => "SI", "promo" => "SI"),
        "SI-NO-SI--" => array("calificacion" => "B", "tipo" => 5, "resutado" => "NO APTO", "tasa" => "SI", "promo" => "SI"),
        // C
        "NO-SI-NO-NO-NO" => array("calificacion" => "C", "tipo" => 1, "resutado" => "APTO", "tasa" => "SI", "promo" => "SI"),
        "NO-SI-NO-NO-SI" => array("calificacion" => "C", "tipo" => 2, "resutado" => "APTO", "tasa" => "SI", "promo" => "SI"),
        "NO-SI-NO-SI-NO" => array("calificacion" => "C", "tipo" => 3, "resutado" => "CON OBSERVACIONES", "tasa" => "SI", "promo" => "SI"),
        "NO-SI-NO-SI-SI" => array("calificacion" => "C", "tipo" => 4, "resutado" => "CON OBSERVACIONES", "tasa" => "SI", "promo" => "SI"),
        "NO-SI-SI--" => array("calificacion" => "C", "tipo" => 5, "resutado" => "NO APTO", "tasa" => "SI", "promo" => "SI"),
        // D
        "NO-NO-NO-NO-NO" => array("calificacion" => "D", "tipo" => 1, "resutado" => "APTO", "tasa" => "SI", "promo" => "SI"),
        "NO-NO-NO-NO-SI" => array("calificacion" => "D", "tipo" => 2, "resutado" => "APTO", "tasa" => "SI", "promo" => "SI"),
        "NO-NO-NO-SI-NO" => array("calificacion" => "D", "tipo" => 3, "resutado" => "CON OBSERVACIONES", "tasa" => "SI", "promo" => "SI"),
        "NO-NO-NO-SI-SI" => array("calificacion" => "D", "tipo" => 4, "resutado" => "CON OBSERVACIONES", "tasa" => "SI", "promo" => "SI"),
        "NO-NO-SI--" => array("calificacion" => "D", "tipo" => 5, "resutado" => "NO APTO", "tasa" => "SI", "promo" => "SI"),
    );

    if (array_key_exists($data, $config)) {
        return $config[$data];
    } else {
        return array("calificacion" => "", "tipo" => "", "resutado" => "", "tasa" => "", "promo" => "");
    }
    
}
```

Comment: That would be the very long way of doing it, but it's basically the same logic as in my answer. Since you have two separate, independent fieldsets that define the result, it's easier (or less verbose) to separate them for lookup, and then combine the outcome. With what you do above, you could -- to not have to spell out the keys a hundred times -- just define your data as e.g. `'NO-NO-SI--' => ['D', 5, 'NO APTO', 'SI', 'SI'],` ... and in the end, `return array_combine($keys, $config[$data])`, where `$keys` is an array of your keys.